# Store a copy of GMSVisibleRegion

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I'd like my map controller to save the visibleRegion when loading markers.  Then as the user moves the map I can compare the current visibleRegion with the region that contains the markers.

I attempted to create a property to save a copy of a GMSVisibleRegion but I'm not understanding something about saving a struct.

So how can I take a snapshot of a visibleRegion and store it in my map controller for reference later?

```
typedef struct {
  CLLocationCoordinate2D nearLeft;
  CLLocationCoordinate2D nearRight;
  CLLocationCoordinate2D farLeft;
  CLLocationCoordinate2D farRight;
} GMSVisibleRegion;
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using, which gives you the errors you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Add an instance variable where you want to store the region:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    GMSVisibleRegion region;
    GMSMapView* mapView;
}
@end
```

Get the current visibleRegion:

```
region = mapView.projection.visibleRegion;
```

Comment: Actually when trying to assign the region you get a memory error EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  Also when saying if (region) xcode complains about `Statement requires expression of scalar type(GMSVisibleRegion) invalid`